# How to invoke a "loose Xaml"-defined activity from another "loose Xaml"-defined activity?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I have two "loose" XAML files, each declarativly defining composite activity which is composed of some custom (compiled) code-activities.

Now, I would like the activity defined in the 1st "loose" Xaml to 'contain' the activity defined in the 2nd "loose" Xaml as of its steps.

However, I have no clue how to 'glue' both activities together such that 1st activity will know to correctly load the activity from the 2nd Xaml.

So when calling:

```
XamlXmlReader xr = new XamlXmlReader(@"FirstLooseActivity.xaml");
ActivityBuilder ab = (ActivityBuilder)XamlServices.Load(ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderReader(xr));
```

I end up with a XamlObjectWriterException (after I loaded all relevant assemblies to my hosting app):

```
Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:SecondLooseActivity}MyActivity
```

Since there is no Xlink support in MS, is there a way to do this at all?

If not, what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and found a solution.

Here's what my XAML looked like this:

```
<Activity ... xmlns:mylib="clr-namespace:MyProject.ActivityLibrary">
    <mylib:MyCustomActivity ... />
</Activity>
```

The trick that worked for me was to specify the assembly containing my custom activity in the namespace.

Changing the namespace to this made it work:

```
xmlns:mylib="clr-namespace:MyProject.ActivityLibrary;assembly=MyProject.ActivityLibrary"
```

Comment: i still have the same error after changing the namespaces. any other idea ?